# Google Cloud Java SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was going through the Google Cloud Java SDK on Github when I came across this line. I don't quite understand the meaning of "**within Compute/App Engine**". This is in with regards to Authentication for Google Cloud Services.

Github Link :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java

*When using google-cloud libraries from within Compute/App Engine, no additional authentication steps are necessary. For example:

```
`Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();`*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Google APIs from anywhere on the internet. If the code accessing GCS is running on a phone, on your desktop, on AWS, on a server in colo, then you will need to do the authentication described.

However if you are accessing the API from code that is already running on Google Cloud Platform, then the authentication is automatically provided.